# ¿Cómo saco datos de una consulta con otra consulta?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo una consulta que me devuelve valores pero no quiero todos solo quiero algunos, por eso tengo otra consulta donde tengo los valores que no quiero, entonces lo que quiero hacer es a la primera consulta quitarle los valores que se encuentran en la segunda consulta.

Esta es mi primera consulta:

```
select cli.codcliente,are.codareacliente,trim(cli.cliente) as cliente,trim(are.areacliente) as areacliente,trim(are.direccion) as direccion ,ubi.nombre as distrito,are.ubigeo,trim(cli.ruc) as ruc,trim(are.telefono) as telefono,trim(are.contacto) as contacto,trim(are.email) as email 
            from cliente cli
            left outer join areacliente are on are.codcliente = cli.codcliente 
            left outer join ubigeos as ubi on ubi.ubigeo=are.ubigeo 
            left outer join t_admin_acceso_det tad on tad.codigo_cliente=are.codcliente and tad.codigo_area_cliente=are.codareacliente 
            left outer join t_admin_acceso as tac on tac.tipo_acceso=tad.tipo_acceso and tac.correlativo=tad.correlativo
```

la segunda es esta:

```
select tc.codcliente from clientearea_lineacredito tc
             left outer join cliente cl on cl.codcliente=tc.codcliente
             left outer join areacliente ar on ar.codcliente=tc.codcliente and ar.codareacliente=tc.codareacliente );
```

las dos consultas tiene algo en comun que existen dos tablas que se relacion por el código las tablas son (clientearea_lineacredito  , cliente )

lo que intente hacer es esto , usando  subconsultas pero me sale este error una subconsulta utilizada como expresión retornó más de un registro

```
select cli.codcliente,are.codareacliente,trim(cli.cliente) as cliente,trim(are.areacliente) as areacliente,trim(are.direccion) as direccion ,ubi.nombre as distrito,are.ubigeo,trim(cli.ruc) as ruc,trim(are.telefono) as telefono,trim(are.contacto) as contacto,trim(are.email) as email 
        from cliente cli
        left outer join areacliente are on are.codcliente = cli.codcliente 
        left outer join ubigeos as ubi on ubi.ubigeo=are.ubigeo 
        left outer join t_admin_acceso_det tad on tad.codigo_cliente=are.codcliente and tad.codigo_area_cliente=are.codareacliente 
        left outer join t_admin_acceso as tac on tac.tipo_acceso=tad.tipo_acceso and tac.correlativo=tad.correlativo 
        where cli.codcliente <> (select tc.codcliente from clientearea_lineacredito tc
             left outer join cliente cl on cl.codcliente=tc.codcliente
             left outer join areacliente ar on ar.codcliente=tc.codcliente and ar.codareacliente=tc.codareacliente );
```

Espero su ayuda.

Comment: Hola Robert, ¿qué manejador de base de datos utilizas? Ya que en las etiquetas veo que pones diferentes manejadores. También es importante mencionar la versión, con esto nos das más detalle para que podamos resolver las dudas que vayan saliendo.

Comment: si es correcto el error la subconsulta devuelve un arreglo, y la primera consulta revisa fila por fila si es distinto de el arreglo, lo que podrias colocar es 
`WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
            tc.codcliente
        FROM
            clientearea_lineacredito tc
                WHERE
            cli.codcliente = tc.codcliente)`

Comment: Es en postrgesql y la herramienta es el pg admin , intente el not exists pero no me sale niguna resultado

Comment: Si lo que quieres es obtener los clientes que no esten en clientearea_lineacredito, puedes usar esto 
`WHERE cli.codcliente NOT IN (SELECT tc.codcliente FROM clientearea_lineacredito)`

Comment: tienes razon era el not in gracias

Comment: En realidad, es casi siempre mejor usar `not exists` en vez de `not in`, porque `not in` puede producir resultados muy raros con valores null. Dijistes que ya probastes `not exists`, pero, lo mas probable es que no lo usastes correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Como se menciona en los comentarios se puede utilizar `NOT EXISTS` para *eliminar* del resultado los registros de la segunda consulta:

```
select
    cli.codcliente,
    are.codareacliente,
    trim(cli.cliente) as cliente,
    trim(are.areacliente) as areacliente,
    trim(are.direccion) as direccion,
    ubi.nombre as distrito,
    are.ubigeo,trim(cli.ruc) as ruc,
    trim(are.telefono) as telefono,
    trim(are.contacto) as contacto,
    trim(are.email) as email
from
    cliente cli
    left outer join areacliente are on
        are.codcliente = cli.codcliente 
    left outer join ubigeos as ubi on
        ubi.ubigeo = are.ubigeo 
    left outer join t_admin_acceso_det tad on
        tad.codigo_cliente = are.codcliente
        and tad.codigo_area_cliente = are.codareacliente 
    left outer join t_admin_acceso as tac on
        tac.tipo_acceso = tad.tipo_acceso
        and tac.correlativo = tad.correlativo
where
    not exists (
        select *
        from
            clientearea_lineacredito tc
        where
            tc.codcliente = cli.codcliente
    )
```

Cabe mencionar que no es necesario incluir toda la segunta consulta, ya que ésta utiliza `left outer join`, las tablas `cliente` y `areacliente` no contribuyen al resultado de la segunda consulta y los registros dependen exclusivamente de la tabla `clientearea_lineacredito`.

También se puede hacer utilizando un `left outer join` en combinación con la búsqueda de valores `null` para únicamente incluir aquellos registros que no tengan coincidencia en la tabla  `clientearea_lineacredito`:

```
select
    cli.codcliente,
    are.codareacliente,
    trim(cli.cliente) as cliente,
    trim(are.areacliente) as areacliente,
    trim(are.direccion) as direccion,
    ubi.nombre as distrito,
    are.ubigeo,trim(cli.ruc) as ruc,
    trim(are.telefono) as telefono,
    trim(are.contacto) as contacto,
    trim(are.email) as email
from
    cliente cli
    left outer join areacliente are on
        are.codcliente = cli.codcliente 
    left outer join ubigeos as ubi on
        ubi.ubigeo = are.ubigeo 
    left outer join t_admin_acceso_det tad on
        tad.codigo_cliente = are.codcliente
        and tad.codigo_area_cliente = are.codareacliente 
    left outer join t_admin_acceso as tac on
        tac.tipo_acceso = tad.tipo_acceso
        and tac.correlativo = tad.correlativo
    left outer join clientearea_lineacredito tc on
        tc.codcliente = cli.codcliente
where
    tc.codcliente is null
```

Estos dos métodos pueden ser más eficientes que utilizar `NOT IN` ya que el optimizador utiliza un `Anti Join` (complemento de la intersección) para determinar que registros no cumplen con la condición de la intersección.  Mientras que `NOT IN` requiere de un barrido (scan) de todos los valores de la tabla `clientearea_lineacredito` y luego un barrido de los valores de la tabla `cliente` para determinar cuáles son los que no cumplen con la condición.  Además `NOT IN` tiene un comportamiento especial con los valores `NULL`.

**Actualización**

En respuesta al comentario de A. Cedano respecto a la utilización de `SELECT *`, en la documentación de PostgreSQL referente a las [consultas subordinadas](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-subquery.html), se indica que al utilizar la expresión `EXISTS` se evalúa la consulta subordinada para determinar si genera o no registros.  Cuando genera al menos un registro el resultado es `true` (verdadero); cuando no genera registros, entonces el resultado es `false` (falso).  Además, se advierte que la consulta subordinada por lo general no se ejecutará hasta generar todos los registros posibles, si no únicamente hasta el punto en el que genera un registro, por lo que no se debe depender de la ejecución completa.  Finalmente, también se indica que dado que el resultado depende únicamente de la existencia de registros y no de su contenido, el listado de la cláusula `SELECT` no es de interés y usualmente se utiliza `SELECT 1`.

También es importante resaltar que la instrucción `SELECT` se ejecuta en un orden diferente al que se escribe y en términos muy generales es:

1. Primero se ejecuta la cláusula `FROM` en la que se determinan las intersecciones de las tablas y/o consultas subordinadas (también conocidas como tablas derivadas).
2. Después de obtener el conjunto de registros a partir de las intersecciones y uniones, se procede al filtrado de los mismos evaluando las condiciones de la cláusula `WHERE`.  En este punto se eliminan los registros que no cumplen con las condiciones escritas.
3. Luego toca el turno a la cláusula `GROUP BY` para agrupar los registros de acuerdo a los valores de los campos indicados y evaluar las funciones de acumulación (`SUM`, `MIN`, `MAX`, etc.).
4. Enseguida se eliminan los grupos que no cumplan las condiciones indicadas en la cláusuala `HAVING`.
5. Se hace la proyección de los registros de acuerdo la lista de campos de la cláusula `SELECT`, hasta este punto los registros *contienen* los campos de todas las tablas.
6. Si se indicó el modificador `DISTINCT` se eliminan los registros duplicados.
7. Se incluye cada `UNION` después de evaluar cada sub-consulta de la unión.
8. Finalmente se ordenan los registros de acuerdo a la clásula `ORDER BY`.

Espero que este orden de evaluación conceptual ayude a ver más claramente como la evaluación de la consulta subordinada dentro de la operación `EXISTS` no depende de la lista de campos indicada en la cláusula `SELECT` y únicamente se incluye de tal manera que se reconozca como un comando `SELECT` de acuerdo a la gramática del lenguaje SQL. El optimizador, en la mayoría de los casos, únicamente ejecutaría hasta el paso 2 conceptual y pararía en cuanto se genere un registro (resultando en `true`) o hasta verificar que no hay registros que cumplan las condiciones (resultando en `false`).

Comment: Pero ya que él dice en la pregunta: _tengo otra consulta donde tengo los valores que no quiero_... ¿Por qué hacer un SELECT * o un SELECT de varios campos de la consulta que él no quiere? Uno hace SELECT de algo que va a usar ¿no? Entonces para qué hacer SELECT sobre tantos campos de la sub consulta?

Comment: La proyección del `SELECT` no importa en la operación `EXISTS`, ya que solo comprueba la existencia o no de registros que cumplan la condición. Igualmente pudiera usarse `SELECT 1` y tendrá el mismo efecto.

Comment: Pues no me convence, o la informática es ilógica o hay algún error en un diseño de BD en el que tengas que hacer un SELECT * que en realidad sería ignorado. ¿Tienes algún enlace a documentación que sostenga tu afirmación?

Comment: @A.Cedano he actualizado mi respuesta con más información al respecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el dato. Ahora me queda más claro. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta anterior es correcta, ya con tu código quedaría así...

```
SELECT cli.codcliente,are.codareacliente,trim(cli.cliente) as cliente,trim(are.areacliente) as areacliente,trim(are.direccion) as direccion ,ubi.nombre as distrito,are.ubigeo,trim(cli.ruc) as ruc,trim(are.telefono) as telefono,trim(are.contacto) as contacto,trim(are.email) as email 
    from cliente cli
    left outer join areacliente are on are.codcliente = cli.codcliente 
    left outer join ubigeos as ubi on ubi.ubigeo=are.ubigeo 
    left outer join t_admin_acceso_det tad on tad.codigo_cliente=are.codcliente and tad.codigo_area_cliente=are.codareacliente 
    left outer join t_admin_acceso as tac on tac.tipo_acceso=tad.tipo_acceso and tac.correlativo=tad.correlativo 
    where cli.codcliente NOT IN (select tc.codcliente from clientearea_lineacredito tc
         left outer join cliente cl on cl.codcliente=tc.codcliente
         left outer join areacliente ar on ar.codcliente=tc.codcliente and ar.codareacliente=tc.codareacliente );
```

Espero haberte ayudado...
Saludos!